# what is the output and explain how?

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment, associativity, operator-precedence

I am confused about the output of following 2 programs. Could someone explain the precedence and associativity rules?

Program 1:

```
char arr[] = "geeksforgeeks";
char *p = arr;
*p++;
printf(" %c", *p);
```

Program 2:

```
char arr[]  = "geeksforgeeks";
char *ptr  = arr;

while(*ptr != '\0')
    ++*ptr++;
printf("%s %s", arr, ptr);
```

Comment: Please don't write code like that. You _can_ does not mean you _have to_.

Comment: Which part, exactly?

Comment: here in first program *p++ is evaluated as *(p++)  because post fix has higher precedence over pointer *

Comment: i am not able to sort out how the second program is evaluating the expression ++*ptr++

Comment: It's evaluated as `++(*(ptr++))`. Postfix `++` has higher precedence than prefix `++` and dereference `*`. The latter two have the same precedence so *associativity* comes in to play, which is right to left for those operators.

Comment: @Bathsheba then how is the output coming as h ,it should be f according to your evaluation.

Comment: Don't forget that the postfix increment is *delayed* until the next sequencing point.

Comment: @Bathsheba Oh sorry i got it. thanks :)

Comment: "I am confused about the output of following 2 programs." That's by design. Programs like 2 are not supposed to be wtitten.

Answer (score 1):

First let's simplify your program into something that's comparable:

```
char arr[] = "geeksforgeeks";
char* p = arr;

*p++;
printf("%s %c\n", arr, *p);

char* ptr = arr;

++*ptr++;
printf("%s %c\n", arr, *ptr);
```

Next lets look at the [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and hypothesize what we expect to happen:

1. Postfix increment (Happens 1<sup>st</sup> because it has the highest precedence of the three operators)
2. Dereference (Happens 2<sup>nd</sup> because operators of precedence 2 associate Right-to-left)
3. Prefix increment (Happens last because it is the leftmost operator of the lowest precedence)

So we expect `*p++` to have no effect, other than advancing `p` to the 2<sup>nd</sup> position because:

1. Postfix increment `p`
2. Dereference the address of `p` without the increment in address

And we expect `++*ptr++` to increment the current character and advance `ptr` to the 2<sup>nd</sup> position because:

1. Postfix increment `ptr`
2. Dereference the address of `ptr` without the increment in address
3. Increment the value of the `char` at the address `ptr`

And by looking at this [<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/5yRIUD) you can see that our hypothesis was correct, we even get a warning that:

> Value computed is not used [-Wunused-value] `*p++`

Our results are:

> geeksforgeeks e
>   heeksforgeeks e